# I don't understand how the Downtime API works and I'm trying to automate scheduling downtime

Tags: go, datadog

The documentation is very unclear when it comes to the DataDog Downtime API.  I've based my example off of the following documentation: https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/downtimes/#schedule-a-downtime

I have the following environment variables set:

```
    DD_APP_TOKEN: Your datadog application token.
    DD_API_TOKEN: Your datadog API token.
    DD_SITE: The address of the DD API server.  Usually "datadoghq.com"
```

My example code:

```
import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/DataDog/datadog-api-client-go/api/v1/datadog"
    "github.com/slack-go/slack"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ctx := datadog.NewDefaultContext(context.Background())

    var DataDogFiltersByTag = []string{
        "printing",
        "OTIS",
        "env:production",
    }

    Message := "Downtime Test"
    var ctime int64 = time.Now().Unix()     // Current Time
    var dtime int64 = ctime + (45 * 60)     // 45 minutes

    body := *datadog.NewDowntime() // Downtime | Schedule a downtime request body.
    body.Message = &Message
    body.Start = &ctime
    end := datadog.NullableInt64{}
    end.Set(&dtime)
    body.End = end
    body.MonitorTags = &DataDogFiltersByTag

    configuration := datadog.NewConfiguration()

    apiClient := datadog.NewAPIClient(configuration)
    resp, r, err := apiClient.DowntimesApi.CreateDowntime(ctx, body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error when calling `DowntimesApi.CreateDowntime`: %v\n", err)
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Full HTTP response: %v\n", r)
    }
    // response from `CreateDowntime`: Downtime
    responseContent, _ := json.MarshalIndent(resp, "", "  ")
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "Response from DowntimesApi.CreateDowntime:\n%s\n", responseContent)
}
```

This results in the following error message:

```
/private/var/folders/p0/jbhf5p4n3f3c3rc5rc_rc6400000gn/T/GoLand/___6go_build_ClusterUpgradeNotification
Error when calling `DowntimesApi.CreateDowntime`: 400 Bad Request
Full HTTP response: &{400 Bad Request 400 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Cache-Control:[no-cache] Connection:[keep-alive] Content-Length:[39] Content-Security-Policy:[frame-ancestors 'self'; report-uri https://api.datadoghq.com/csp-report] Content-Type:[application/json] Date:[Wed, 03 Nov 2021 00:33:09 GMT] Pragma:[no-cache] Strict-Transport-Security:[max-age=15724800;] X-Content-Type-Options:[nosniff] X-Frame-Options:[SAMEORIGIN]] {{"errors": ["Invalid scope parameter"]}} 39 [] false false map[] 0xc00019a800 0xc0003342c0}
Response from DowntimesApi.CreateDowntime:
{}

Process finished with the exit code 1
```

Comment: Does it work if you execute the non-modified version of the example code?

Comment: No. It doesn't.

Comment: In the line below the code example in the docs, it says to use `DD_API_KEY` and `DD_APP_KEY` but you have `DD_API_TOKEN` and `DD_APP_TOKEN`. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Ok nevermind, I saw you fixed it yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scope is a required parameter in datadog.CreateDowntime().  Adding body.SetScope([]string{"*"}) resolved my issue.